# how to handle capital case in JSON?

Tags: haskell, aeson

This is a stupid question, and I have tried to understand from different tutorials. When having a JSON with capital case Haskell crashes as explained by others (https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/beginners/2013-October/012865.html). As suggested it could be solved with deriving from deriveFromJSON. DeriveJSON requires a function input, how should I write the derive statement in the below code? I am missing something in my understanding, and would appreciate any help.

```
import Data.Aeson.TH

data Person = Person { 
        Foo :: String
        , bar :: String
    } deriving (Eq, Show, deriveJSON)

main = do 
let b = Person "t" "x" 
print b
```

Comment: Change your `Foo` to `foo`. Note that `foo` is a function that you get for free from Record syntax. You cannot have capital case for function names in Haskell. This has got nothing to do with handling capital case in JSON.

Comment: ok, I thought that deriveJSON allowed the capital casing to match. So how could I decode a person object with capital letter within a JSON to match with my data object with lower casing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`deriveJSON` and friends are Template Haskell functions which will generate instances for you. As such, you should not try to list them in the `deriving` clause. Instead, call them in a splice at the top level like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Data.Aeson.TH

data Person = Person { 
    foo :: String,
    bar :: String
} deriving (Eq, Show)

$(deriveJSON defaultOptions ''Person)
```

As mentioned in the mailing list, you can customize the field names by overriding the `fieldLabelModifier` function of the `defaultOptions` record, for example this will change the JSON name of `foo` to `Foo`:

```
$(deriveFromJSON defaultOptions {
    fieldLabelModifier = let f "foo" = "Foo"
                             f other = other
                         in f
} ''Person)
```

Comment: @hammar-with that code should I not be able to write (decode "{\"Foo\":\"TEXT\",\"bar\":\"x\"}" :: Maybe Person) >>= print in the main?

Comment: @hotGopher: Yes, except for the `>>= print` part, since `decode` is a pure function. `print  (decode "{\"Foo\":\"TEXT\",\"bar\":\"x\"}" :: Maybe Person)` should work, though, assuming you have `OverloadedStrings` enabled (`decode` takes a lazy `ByteString`).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any control of the instance being generated? If so, don't emit keys starting with capital letters.

If not: Just define the instance yourself instead of deriving it. It's just a couple lines of code.